# rm: cannot remove `/run/user/root/gvfs': Is a directory

Tags: 12.10, sudo, rm

Whenever I type a command which is similar to `sudo apt-get install` or anything like this I get this kind of error:

```
$ sudo su
# exit
exit
rm: cannot remove `/run/user/root/gvfs': Is a directory
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Please, could you paste the whole output and possibly the command that produces the error? Thanks!

Comment: A very simple command,: kbkb@Abood:~$ sudo su
root@Abood:/home/kbkb# exit
exit
rm: cannot remove `/run/user/root/gvfs': Is a directory.
I'm sorry because i don't know how paste it like a code here

Comment: GVFS is the GNOME Virtual File System. Does it help to unmount gvfs? Use `gvfs-mount -l` or `gvfs-mount -li` to get a list of mounted resources and `gvfs-mount -u URI` to unmount a given resource, where URI is the mounted resource.

Comment: I don't actually know where this problem comes from, i don't know what do i have to do, i need a help please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open your terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run this:

```
sudo umount /run/user/root/gvfs
```

Comment: I ran umount /run/user/root/gvfs and it worked thanks.

Comment: If you are already a **root** already, you can run this command without _sudo_ `umount /run/user/root/gvfs`.