# Why I am getting this "cannot remove" line in terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I use Terminal a lot. And just recently noticed this line popping in right after I stop being *root* (after i type `exit`).

> /bin/rm: cannot remove `/run/user/root/gvfs': Is a directory

Why/What is this stand from?

[image]

Does this affect somehow my system's functionality (as I didn't noticed)?

- If so, How can I fix this?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [rm: cannot remove `/run/user/root/gvfs': Is a directory](http://askubuntu.com/questions/233668/rm-cannot-remove-run-user-root-gvfs-is-a-directory)

Comment: In my case is `/bin/rm:...` instead of `rm:...`. Not sure if this is a **big** difference, but this is exactly why I couldn't see this post from the search engine...

Comment: it is the same, `/bin` is in the `PATH` :)

Comment: I understood that the same problem, even the solution is the same. But I just could not find it, as nor **Head** nor _Body_ have this `PATH`. AskUbuntu (google as well I assume) search engine did not give me any results... Sorry for the duplicate. _Should I delete this question and improve the other (older) one?_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [Launchapad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1077569) you should run

```
umount /run/user/root/gvfs
```

before exiting.

Comment: Do I have to run this every time before exiting terminal?

Comment: Well, hopefully no

Comment: Nope, It worked for many times since once typed this in... Thank you.